# Select lines that does not include null in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select clients only when all the lines in Credit are filled. From the table I want to see only the lines for Client 1, Client 3, Client 4 and Client 5.

I was trying this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT client FROM table WHERE [CREDIT] = 'cred')
```

But not working...

Thanks!

| Client | Credit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CRED |
| 1 | CRED |
| 1 | CRED |
| 1 | CRED |
| 1 | CRED |
| 2 |  |
| 2 | CRED |
| 2 | CRED |
| 3 | CRED |
| 3 | CRED |
| 3 | CRED |
| 3 | CRED |
| 4 | CRED |
| 4 | CRED |
| 5 | CRED |
| 6 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 6 | CRED |
| 6 | CRED |

Comment: Hint: EXISTS/NOT EXISTS conditions typically has _correlated_ subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self-(antisemi)join for this:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM table t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM table t2
                    WHERE t1.client = t2.client
                      AND t2.credit IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT client, count(credit)  FROM t
group by client
having count(client) = sum(case when credit is null then 0 else 1 end)
```